# How to enable Submit Button after filling out the required fields in webforms?

Tags: webforms, 10

I have Added A condition on webform where submit button is enabled when on required field is filled
as in below screen shot.[image]

But when last name or phone code is filled the field enable, sometimes on filling all fields also submit is disable.
[image]

```
first_name:
  '#type': textfield
  '#title': 'First Name'
  '#placeholder': 'First name'
  '#required': true
last_name:
  '#type': textfield
  '#title': 'Last Name'
  '#placeholder': 'Last name'
  '#required': true
birthday_child_name:
  '#type': textfield
  '#title': 'Birthday Child Name'
  '#placeholder': 'Birthday child name'
  '#required': true
preferred_date_of_party:
  '#type': textfield
  '#title': 'Preferred Date of Party'
  '#placeholder': dd/mm/yyyy
  '#readonly': true
  '#required': true
  '#attributes':
    class:
      - datepicker
preferred_hour:
  '#type': select
  '#title': 'Preferred Hour'
  '#options':
    1: '1'
    2: '2'
    3: '3'
    4: '4'
  '#empty_option': Select
  '#required': true
venue:
  '#type': select
  '#title': Venue
  '#options':
    Motiongate: Motiongate
    'Very Smurfy Café': 'Very Smurfy Café'
    'Dragon Glame Grill': 'Dragon Glame Grill'
    'King Julens Café': 'King Julens Café'
    "Baby Brent's Luncheonette": "Baby Brent's Luncheonette"
    'Neon Galaxy': 'Neon Galaxy'
    'Neon Galaxy - Atlas': 'Neon Galaxy - Atlas'
    'Neon Galaxy - Orion': 'Neon Galaxy - Orion'
    'Neon Galaxy - Aurora': 'Neon Galaxy - Aurora'
    'Neon Galaxy - Comet': 'Neon Galaxy - Comet'
    'Neon Galaxy - Metor': 'Neon Galaxy - Metor'
    'The Green Planet': 'The Green Planet'
    'Learning Centre 1': 'Learning Centre 1'
    'Learning Centre 2': 'Learning Centre 2'
    'Learning Centre 3': 'Learning Centre 3'
    Riverland: Riverland
    JumpX: JumpX
    'Roxy Cinema': 'Roxy Cinema'
  '#empty_option': Select
  '#required': true
number_of_children_from_3_to_14_years_old:
  '#type': number
  '#title': 'Number of Children from 3 to 14 years old'
  '#placeholder': '0'
  '#required': true
  '#attributes':
    class:
      - disable-pluse-minus
number_of_adults:
  '#type': number
  '#title': 'Number of adults'
  '#placeholder': '0'
  '#required': true
  '#attributes':
    class:
      - disable-pluse-minus
email:
  '#type': email
  '#title': Email
  '#placeholder': 'Enter your email'
  '#required': true
  '#pattern': '[\w+-]+(?:\.[\w+-]+)*@[\w+-]+(?:\.[\w+-]+)*(?:\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4})'
  '#default_value': '[current-user:mail]'
container:
  '#type': container
  '#attributes':
    class:
      - phone-section
  country_code:
    '#type': select
    '#title': 'Country Code'
    '#options': country_phone_code
    '#required': true
  phone_number:
    '#type': tel
    '#title': 'Phone Number'
    '#placeholder': 'Enter your phone number'
    '#required': true
interested_in:
  '#type': checkboxes
  '#title': 'Interested in'
  '#options':
    'Furniture Rental': 'Furniture Rental'
    Audio-Visuals: Audio-Visuals
    Photographer: Photographer
    'Food & Beverage': 'Food & Beverage'
    'Entertainment Services': 'Entertainment Services'
    'Themed Decor': 'Themed Decor'
    'Gift Favors': 'Gift Favors'
    Mascot: Mascot
    Cake: Cake
    'Invitation cards': 'Invitation cards'
actions:
  '#type': webform_actions
  '#title': 'Submit button(s)'
```

Comment: Provide the YAML of a minimal form that displays the problem. Also, I am not certain what you are asking. Some of the English is not understandable.

Comment: added meta data for webform

Comment: There are no conditions in the code sample.